# Logistic regression using rms: calculate odds ratio and p-value for specific unit of change

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I try to calculate the odds ratios and p-values for continuous and categorical predictors at a specific unit of change (e.g. odds ratio for a change of 10 years, not 1 year) of a multiple logistic regression model.

**library:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rms)
```

**my test data:**

```
data <- tibble(age=c(50,49,13,20,100,80,25,110,25,25,13,54,23,45,27,87,55,22),
        dose=c(400,800,800,200,100,450,400,432,543,3245,654,554,64,356,543,321,356,432),
        class=c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1))
```

**my analysis:**

```
dd <- datadist(data);  options(datadist='dd')
g <- lrm(class ~ age+dose, data=data)
```

**What I tried:**

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627237/convert-odds-ratio-of-unit-change-to-whole-range I learned that I could calculate the odds ratio for a specific unit of change with:

```
#calculate odds ratio of age for a multiple of 10 years (10-units-change)
unit.change=c(10)
exp(coef(g)["age"]*unit.change)
```

I do not know how to calculate a p-value for this odds ratio now.

```
print(g)
```

gives me p-values for the beta coefficients, can I use these p-values?

From https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/3.1-0/topics/summary.rms I learned that `summary.rms` calculates inter-quartile range effects. Can I somehow use `summary.rms` to calculate odds ratios at specific unit of change (and corresponding p-values) for every predictor? (my real data has multiple categorical and continuous predictors...).

Comment: (1) This is not multivariate regression: it's *multiple* regression.  (2) It's unclear what you mean by a "p-value for this odds ratio" (for a ten-year change): could you tell us what hypothesis you are testing and show us how it differs from the usual null hypothesis that the coefficient is zero?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I corrected (1). Regarding (2) I would like to give a p-value for the odds ratio that I calculate from the coefficient, is it the same as for the underlying coefficient? I would like to calculate an odds ratio that reflects not an 1-unit-change but a 10-unit-change for years.

Comment: There's no such thing as a p-value for a parameter.  P-values relate to *hypothesis tests.*  In order to explain what you're looking for, you need to tell us what you are testing.

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the OR is 1

Comment: Isn't that precisely the null hypothesis that is automatically tested by the software output?

Comment: I think so. I wondered if the p-values of the b coefficient of a 1-unit change is also valid to the OR of a 10-unit change that is calculated from the b coefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the p-value for the effect of a 10-unit change in the covariate (years in this case) is the same as that for the effect of a 1-unit change.  Here's the demonstration: the p-value for the original question (effect of a 1-unit change) is $P(|Z|>\frac{\hat\beta}{\sigma_{\hat\beta}})$, i.e. the tail area of the Normal distribution beyond the ratio of (estimated change)/(standard error of estimated change).  The estimated effect of a 10-unit change in the covariate is $10\hat\beta$, but the standard error of this change is $10\sigma_{\hat\beta}$; the changes cancel out and we end up with the same p-value as before.

In the case of a logistic regression you will be doing tests on the *log-odds ratio* scale [or equivalently on the scale of additive changes in the log-odds], but the concept is the same.